# Graph vertices selection for paths sum minimalization

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, combinatorial-optimization

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a simple, finite, weighted, undirected, connected graph. Let $P = \{p_{ij}, p_{kl}, p_{il}, ... \}$ be a set of paths, where $p_{ij}$ is a path from $i$-th to $j$-th vertex. Is there an algorithm, that finds vertices $i, j, k, l, ...$ that minimizes the sum of $P$?

Alternative formulations of the question (that I could think of) are:

- finding the vertices permutation that minimizes the sum of $P$,
- embedding paths $P$ into a graph $G$ in such a way that the sum of $P$ is minimal.

I'm happy to provide any additional information about the problem.

**Notes:**

- I've tried looking for the answer independently, but I was usually redirected to Dijkstra's algorithm, which is not the solution.
- I believe that this problem may be related to some kind of routing problem, but I had no luck in finding a satisfactory answer.
- This is not a TSP problem, since there's no limit on how many times the vertices can be accessed. Also, the paths in $P$ can be disjoint.

Comment: Not clear what you want. Are you selecting vertices or paths? How many?

Comment: Is $P$ given or is $P$ what you look for? Specifically the $p_{ij}$ fixed, or is part of the problem to select them?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear (I'm doing the best I can). I'll investigate the first answer and then reformulate the question so that I hopefully make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is unclear, so I'm guessing a bit.

First, make a weighted complete graph $K$, where the weight of edge $ij$ is the distance in $G$ from $i$ to $j$.

Now you want a minimum weight perfect matching in $K$. To do this, let $M$ be the largest weight of an edge in $K$.  Replace each weight $w$ in $K$ by $M+1-w$.  Now you want a maximum weight perfect matching in $K$, and since all the edges are present with a strictly positive weight, that is the same as the maximum weight matching in $K$, which is a [well-studied problem with polynomial time practical solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_weight_matching).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As far as I can tell it looks reasonable and practically what I need, but I'll investigate it to be sure. I'll come back to this question as soon as I'm done.

Comment: In my case, the resultant sub-graph allows nodes of arbitrary degree (actually I expect a lot of them to be of degree 0, most of the time, and often of degree > 1). The minimum weight perfect matching (or any matching, as far as I understand) is not a solution to my problem, but I believe that your input allows me to reformulate my question better. I'll do that when I've got the moment. Thank you!